# Neo4j query relationship property

Tags: mysql, neo4j

Neo4j newbie here.
I have a graph database with node as Person, edges between nodes are relationship POSTED, POSTED has property "message", now I would like to return relationship with certain message. I wrote query like:

```
MATCH (ppl) -[p:POSTED]->(s)
WHERE p.message = "How are you?"
RETURN p
```

It returns nothing.

What is the right way to make relationship queries?
Can I make some queries like:

```
MATCH (a) -[:KNOWS]->(ppl),
(ppl) -[p:POSTED]->(s)
WHERE p.message = "How are you?"
RETURN p
```

Comment: What do you get if try the following query:
MATCH (ppl) -[p:POSTED]->(s)
RETURN p
LIMIT 10

Comment: I will reture all the nods with POSTED relationship to others. Here is how edge added: (Nick)-[:POSTED {messsage: 'How are you?'}]->(Sam)

Comment: Are the three sss in messsage a typo?

Comment: It was provided by someone else. That is why it not working. Thank you. I'm so embarrassed. How do I close this question?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a lot of same Relations between two nodes is not a good idea if you want to create something like a chat.

In fact, it'll be a lot more easier and faster to create a model like this:

```
(:User{Foo:"Bar})-[:POSTED]->(:Message{content:"Hello World"})-[:SENT_TO]->(:User{Foo:"blabla"})
```

This way, you'll be able to store way more thing in your messages and It's easier to do operations with nodes.

You can check [this reddit topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/Neo4j/comments/2m7yoc/question_best_practices_for_multiple/) to find out the best practices to do what you want.